# Сделать палиндром

Tags: python

Нужно найти самый длинный палиндром из входящей строки средством удаления символов из этой строки (удалять можно неограниченное кол-во символов, но менять их порядок нельзя)  
**Входящие данные:** 
test
**Выходящие данные** 
tet

---

Я смог написать код, который выполняет эту задачу, но он немного не укладывается по времени (проходит 31 тест из 34). Возможно как-то ускорить мой код, или стоит использовать другой алгоритм? Буду очень благодарен, если поможете мне с кодом!

```
def palSubSeq(L, string, left, right):
    if L[left][right] == -1:
        if string[left] == string[right]:
            L[left][right] = palSubSeq(L, string, left+1, right-1) + 2
        else:
            L[left][right] = max(palSubSeq(L, string, left+1, right) , palSubSeq(L, string, left, right-1))
    return L[left][right]

def palChars(L, palindrome, left, right, palLeft, palRight):
    while left <= right:
        if left==right and L[left][right]==1:
            palindrome[palLeft] = string[left]
            palLeft += 1
            left += 1
        else:
            if string[left] == string[right]:
                palindrome[palLeft] = string[left]
                palLeft += 1
                left += 1

                palindrome[palRight] = string[right]
                palRight -= 1
                right -= 1
            else:
                if L[left+1][right] >= L[left][right-1]:
                    left += 1
                else:
                    right -= 1

def search_pal(string):
    N = len(string)
    palindrome = ['_' for _ in range(N)]
    L = [[-1] * N for _ in range(N)]

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if i==j:
                L[i][j] = 1
            elif i>j:
                L[i][j] = 0
    palSubSeq(L, string, 0, N-1)
    palChars(L, palindrome, 0, N-1, 0, L[0][N-1])
    return ''.join(filter('_'.__ne__, palindrome)) 

string = input()
if string == string[::-1]:
    palindrome = string[::-1]
else:
    palindrome = search_pal(string)
print(palindrome)
```

Comment: Только на днях обсуждался точно такой же вопрос. Попробуйте поискать поиском тут.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, и правда, нашел. Но только не один из предложенных вариантов из того обсуждения так же не подошел(